# Finding the cheapest combinations of ingredients for feed.

Tags: linear-algebra, word-problem

I need to find the combination of two ingredients out of four given that will give me a 18% by weight protein content at 20 tons.
The ingredients are:

Barley- 11% protein, $131.81 a ton,

Corn- 9% protein, $133.63 a ton

Cottonseed meal- 41% protein, $257.00 a ton

Soybean meal- 48% protein, $301.00 a ton.

What equations do I setup that let me find the combinations?

Do I need to try all different combinations or can I use less equations. I can only use two different ingredients to reach the desired 18% protein at 20 tons.

Answer (score 0):

You need one ingredient that is more than $18\%$ protein and one that is less, so there are only four combinations to try.  Compute the total amount of protein that you need.  Then if you have $x$ of one ingredient and $20-x$ of the other, compute $x$ to get that much protein.  You can use that to compute the total cost of the mix.